# Save As dialog box in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I just want to know how will I show the "Save As" dialog box when I click a button.

I want to save a web page in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the call for the dialog

If you dont initialize the dialog, you don't have to pass "open" for it to show:

$("#dialog").dialog();

Also, this code needs to be on a $(document).ready(); function or be below the elements for it to work.